# drupal---link redirection

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

i used cck and link module to create a link field for my "test" content type, now i want to the link field can rediect to the actual link. eg: the link field is filled by "google" which i want to is when the visitor click the link's name, it rediects to google.com. any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused to what it is that you are asking.  What is it that you want?  When they click on the link that says "google", it guess to "google.com"?  It should do that on its own.  Please provide a few more details to what you're trying to do.

Comment: because there are lots of urls on my site, in order to SEO, so i want to redirecr to the URL, how should i do?

Comment: What, precisely isn't happening? For example, are the links not appearing at all, are they appearing but not forwarding to the correct URL, etc?

Comment: Sir, what I guess you mean is that, the link field has name/title attribute, and also URL attribute, so after posting new "test", the user sees the link title only, but he can click on it to be redirected to its full URL, am I right?

Comment: yeap! do you know how to do it? thank you

Comment: What Version of cck and link module are you using?

Answer (score 0):

go to "admin/content/node-type//fields" (replace  with test for your case, as it's your content type),

then go to "edit" your link field, then under settings you must check "Validate URL" and uncheck "Optional URL", then also select "Required Title", and save,

now when you create new "test" content, you must enter both link title, and link URL,
when it's showed, it'll only shows the link title redirecting to the link URL,

Regards,